# CKEditor "protects" me from inline stylesheets

Tags: regex, wordpress, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm trying to integrate CKEditor into Wordpress for a client. I'm not too familiar with it, it's the first time I use it.

The client wants to use CKEditor on a textarea that gets stored into a custom field and is displayed in the sidebar of a page.

I added support for this form of editing by adding meta boxes to the page edit window. I have FCKEditor plugin installed, so I just call `CKEditor.replace` on the relevant metabox.

The problem is that when the meta box contains *THIS*: (I trimmed the CSS for convenience. There's actually quite a bit).

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.side-banner .style1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.side-banner .style2 {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 12px;
-->
</style>
<table width="246" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="246" height="15" colspan="2" scope="col"> </th>
```

CKEditor turns it into this:

```
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--{cke_protected}%3C!%2D%2D%0A.side-banner%20.style1%20%7B%0A%09font-family%3A%20Arial%2C.side-banner%20.style2%20%7B%0A%09font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20sans-serif%3B-->
</style></p>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="246">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
```

My client insists on editing the sidebox at the CSS/HTML level rather than just content, and I'd like to provide what is requested rather than spend time educating them (this, perhaps, is a topic for another S.O. question?).

I realise this has to do with `CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource` but I found very little documentation to help me, and I wouldn't know what kind of RegEx to provide to avoid this.

How do I keep CKEditor from gobbling up the HTML/CSS code in this `<textarea>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the HTML comments (<!-- and -->) from the <style>

Edit: It's tracked in this ticket http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/4880

Comment: THANKS. So why does CKEditor do that?

Comment: Because in order to avoid problems with the browsers it needs to protect some code like comments, but the process to return everything back to normal has problems with the protection in some cases.